# Why can't Tor Browser transfer data after modem/router restarted?

Tags: relays, network-configuration

My Tor Browser version is 6.5 on Linux (but this was happening since at least 6.0.6, and possibly 6.0.5 on Windows but the system crashed so I can't confirm). It does not happen with the standalone Tor program.

Anyway, my network connection fails frequently and must be manually restarted. If I have Tor Browser open, I have to close-and-reopen it because it's stuck loading any pages (just "Connected to www.example.com") Until I get "The connection has timed out" error from Firefox backend.

Tor log (The network failed twice)

```
02/09/2017 12:15:18.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
02/09/2017 12:15:19.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
02/09/2017 12:15:19.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
02/09/2017 12:15:19.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
02/09/2017 12:15:19.800 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
02/09/2017 12:15:22.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
02/09/2017 12:15:22.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
02/09/2017 12:15:22.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
02/09/2017 12:15:22.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
02/09/2017 12:15:23.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
02/09/2017 12:15:25.900 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
02/09/2017 12:15:25.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
02/09/2017 12:15:32.500 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
02/09/2017 12:15:33.000 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
02/09/2017 13:25:51.600 [NOTICE] No circuits are opened. Relaxed timeout for circuit 15 (a Measuring circuit timeout 3-hop circuit in state doing handshakes with channel state open) to 267350ms. However, it appears the circuit has timed out anyway. 1 guards are live. 
02/09/2017 13:25:51.600 [NOTICE] Tor has not observed any network activity for the past 706 seconds. Disabling circuit build timeout recording. 
!!02/09/2017 13:43:28.600 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
!!02/09/2017 13:46:28.600 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
02/09/2017 13:51:56.900 [NOTICE] Our IP address has changed.  Rotating keys... 
02/09/2017 13:51:58.300 [NOTICE] Tor now sees network activity. Restoring circuit build timeout recording. Network was down for 2272 seconds during 3 circuit attempts. 
02/09/2017 14:32:00.600 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
02/09/2017 14:34:38.600 [NOTICE] Tor has not observed any network activity for the past 1656 seconds. Disabling circuit build timeout recording. 
02/09/2017 14:35:15.600 [NOTICE] No circuits are opened. Relaxed timeout for circuit 338 (a Measuring circuit timeout 3-hop circuit in state doing handshakes with channel state open) to 267350ms. However, it appears the circuit has timed out anyway. 0 guards are live. [4 similar message(s) suppressed in last 3600 seconds] 
02/09/2017 14:54:28.300 [NOTICE] Our IP address has changed.  Rotating keys... 
02/09/2017 14:54:30.100 [NOTICE] Tor now sees network activity. Restoring circuit build timeout recording. Network was down for 2847 seconds during 8 circuit attempts. 
!!02/09/2017 14:56:23.600 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
!!02/09/2017 14:56:24.700 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit)
```

The entries with leading "!!" qre what I think are the problems (i.e. the relays). Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Your connection seems quite bad and Tor believes your guard is down: `However, it appears the circuit has timed out anyway. 0 guards are live. [4 similar message(s) suppressed in last 3600 seconds]`

Comment: Is there a way to extend the timeout?

Comment: [Yes](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#CircuitBuildTimeout) but it's probably not the solution for your problem. What is going wrong with your internet connection?

Comment: I'm quite far from my ISPs signal tower and I usually get "Connection Reset" errors while I'm browsing (though I'm still connected). My ISP groups us behind an IP address that changes frequently (kind of like what AOL does).

Comment: look in the left said: **[NOTICE]** , don't worry. it's control flow. of TOR

Answer (score 1):

This problem is an illusion - it's actually a internet connection problem like canonizing ironize said. I managed to load some sites on Tor Browser after the network failure (albeit 2x slower than normal), I'm planning to ditch my current modem anyway.

Answer (score -2):

If you do **not** experience the same problems with a standalone Tor program - it looks suspicious then. The lines like the ones you've marked wit `!!` are stating that in 120 minutes you have no luck connecting to the destination - and there can be quite a *huge pile of reasons* to cause it.

The first obvious reason - the connection problem - is not the likely candidate due to the fact that you're not experiencing such kind of trouble when using a standalone Tor. The browser bundle makes dynamic tweaks to the Tor via control port/socket, i.e. uses telnet command protocol to constantly monitor and control the binary Tor instance, like a "dynamic configuration" mode. And this "autopilot" seems to fail in your case.

Try to use standalone Tor + Firefox + FoxyProxy - that's the simpliest solution you can use here. And you're not alone in this trouble - I used to experience it with a browser too, that's why I'm not using Tor Browser Bundle.

Comment: *"The browser bundle makes dynamic tweaks to the Tor via control port/socket, i.e. uses telnet command protocol to constantly monitor and control the binary Tor instance, like a "dynamic configuration" mode. And this "autopilot" seems to fail in your case."* No, it does not.

Comment: *"Try to use standalone Tor + Firefox + FoxyProxy"* No, do not do this it is dangerous and will not be anonymous.

Comment: @canonizingironize If having a bad habbit - yes, neither Firefox, nor Tor Browser will save you - and the Firefox has lesser anonymity *by design* than Tor Browser does. But no one stops you from using Firefox inside a VM - and the anonymity becomes comparable, if not greater. So leveraging *the setup* according to the anonymity required is the right way. And about the dynamical tweaks - you're wrong, check the logs and code - it **does** such a stuff...

Comment: *"and the anonymity becomes comparable, if not greater"* No, it does not.

Comment: @canonizingironize oh, really? why is that? And how it is *less* secure, if I have a linux with a virtual network, connected to the Tor VM, the Tor VM uses NO routing at all, just a socks port enabled - others are firewalled. HOW it's less secure? It's actually greater ;) If you think I'm wrong - would you be so kind to bring up a technical proof?

Comment: No one is talking about security, we're talking about *anonymity* which is a different concept.

Comment: so - how it will hurt the anonymity?

Comment: https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/

Comment: @canonizingironize thank you, Captain Obviousnes! and is there any real data? a VM is much more secure and anonymous/unfingerprintable nowdays, check the `VBoxManage` manpage at least ;)

Comment: No, it's not. You will lack the circuit isolation, cache isolation, new identity, new circuits, audiocontext fingerprinting protections, canvas fingerprinting protections, software stack fingerprinting protections, resource:// reading protections and a lot of other protections which you **clearly do not know even exist so maybe you should stop advising other users to make the same mistakes that you do out of your own ignorance**

Comment: @canonizingironize go Read The Fine Manuals, and don't sound as a bookworm *again*, please! If you don't know something - it's TOTALLY OK to ask! You're speaking about a ciruit isolation, for example, but - I see, that you can't even undrestand what it's really is in a Firefox: yes, Tor Browser is a tweaked Firefox, just you know...

Comment: Alexey, you're wrong and I have no more time for you. Go back to trying to sell your 1 line 6 hop tor patch on crowdfunding sites.

Comment: Please discuss issues next time at [The Exit Node](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10754/the-exit-node).